# FILTER duplicate head bindings in RDF Collection CONSTRUCT with SPARQL 1.1

Tags: sparql, rdf, json-ld

I am trying to CONSTRUCT complete RDF Collections with a SPARQL 1.1 property path.  The property path examples that I have seen are able to get the rdf:first nodes, but I have yet to see one that is able to get the whole chain, including the bnodes.  The key parts of the query look like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sc: <http://iiif.io/api/presentation/2#>

CONSTRUCT {?range sc:hasCanvases ?listid .
?listid rdf:first ?canvas .
?listid rdf:rest ?mid .
?mid rdf:rest ?node .
?node rdf:first ?canvas .
?node rdf:rest ?last .
[...]}

WHERE {values ?range {<http://some.uri>}
?range sc:hasCanvases ?listid .
values ?e { rdf:first rdf:rest } 
?listid rdf:rest* ?mid . 
?mid ?e ?node FILTER (?mid != ?node). 
?listid rdf:first ?first .
?node rdf:first ?canvas .
?node rdf:rest ?last .
[...]}
```

It mostly works, except that the ?listid node binds to every `rdf:rest ?mid` object in the property path.

There is a [referencedOnce](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js/blob/master/js/jsonld.js#L3233) constraint in the `jsonld.fromRDF` method that makes these extra head triples problematic for list reconstruction with that library. I have tried a variety of subqueries, property paths and FILTERS, but am quite stuck on this.  Is it possible?

Comment: It would help if you could show the complete construct query you're using.  It's not clear what you're trying to construct, since you left that part out.   It's also not clear what you mean by "head node";  there's no `?head` in the query...

Comment: thank you for this solution @JoshuaTaylor   
the problem was in the CONSTRUCT part of the query (I have added it now for clarity).  I simply changed from this:  `?range sc:hasCanvases ?listid .`   `?listid rdf:first ?canvas .` `?listid rdf:rest ?mid .`    
to this:  `?range sc:hasCanvases ?listid .` 
    `?mid rdf:first ?canvas .` 
    `?mid rdf:rest ?last .`
 and it works.  
It seems that the subject of the property path is iteratively bound to every matching object in the path.  So when referenced in CONSTRUCT, it shows a pattern like 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but it *sounds* like you want to write a **construct** query that will contain a list that's present in the data.  It's much easier if you provide sample data, and if you show the complete query that you're trying to use, because then we have much less to guess about.  Under this assumption, let's start with some data.  Here are two things with a property relating each one to a list of values:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :hasList (1 2 3 4 5) .
:b :hasList (6 7 8 9 0) .
```

Here's a query that retrieves the list associated with **:a** and constructs it:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

construct {
  ?mid rdf:first ?value ;
       rdf:rest ?tail .
}
where {
  :a :hasList ?list .
  ?list rdf:rest* ?mid .
  ?mid rdf:first ?value .
  ?mid rdf:rest ?tail .
}
```

And the results:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="urn:ex:">
  <rdf:Description>
    <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
            <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
            >5</rdf:first>
          </rdf:rest>
          <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
          >4</rdf:first>
        </rdf:rest>
        <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >3</rdf:first>
      </rdf:rest>
      <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
      >2</rdf:first>
    </rdf:rest>
    <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
    >1</rdf:first>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

There **where** part can even be made a bit more concise, since you don't use the value of **?list**:

```sql
  :a :hasList/rdf:rest* ?mid .
  ?mid rdf:first ?value .
  ?mid rdf:rest ?tail .
```

Comment: I am returning to this problem once again and am finding that the first rdf:first of the list is not returned by the query.  (e.g. ?list also has an rdf:first)  This is the important part because the json-ld library needs to identify the list "head" in order to reconstruct the sequence.  The construction of a collection has the semantics of: ?list rdf:first <head> . ?list rdf:rest _:b1 . _:b1 rdf:first <second> ... and so on.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson The query provided does get the first element in the list.  The key is that the property path in `?list rdf:rest* ?mid .
  ?mid rdf:first ?value .` uses * which means that one of the values of ?mid is the same as ?list,so one of the values of ?value is the first element in the list.

Comment: so if the syntax construct is (elt* A path of zero or more occurrences of elt), and the value ?list is only an occurence of :hasList, it seems strange that ?list would also be an occurrence of rdf:rest, no?  What is crazy to me, is that it indeed did work on one data set, and now it is not working, so I cannot say with any certainty that this is incorrect.  My current workaround is to initially get the?list rdf:rest node and use it as a static construct value in the query (to avoid the duplicates) and also to add a variable for the ?list rdf:first as ?first... then everything works.

Comment: @Christopher When the property path is of length zero, it means that the beginning and the end are the same node.  So ?a p* ?b matches with ?a == ?b,even if there are no triples using property p.

Comment: Quick follow up.  I fixed the issue in my data that was causing the missing first element.  rdf:rest was not set to rdf:nil, in a child node "sublist" of the element.  Without these rdf:nil tail statements, the jsonld list constructor does not work.  Regarding the property path length of zero functioning as an identity property, this is very interesting and useful to know, and confirmed correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `rdf:rest*/rdf:first` idiom to get all members in the list.  Try the following (I'm assuming that `?listid` contains one or more RDF Collection(list)):

```
SELECT ?node
WHERE {
   values ?sequence {<http://some.uri>}
   ?sequence eg:hasThings ?listid .
   ?listid rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?node .
}
```